# Google Dataflow write not in order

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a `PCollection<List<KV<String,Long>>`  , I ordered the list with `Top` transformation and `OrderByValue` but when I wrote the result to file it is not in order.

```
public class StringFormatResult extends DoFn<List<KV<String, Long>>, String> {    

    @Override
    public void processElement(ProcessContext context) {
        for (KV<String, Long> item : context.element()) {
            context.output(item.getKey() + " | " + item.getValue());
        }
    }
} 



p.apply(TextIO.Read.named("ReadLines").from(options.getInputFile()))
     .apply("Word counter phase",new WordCounter())     
     .apply(TextIO.Write.named("WriteCounts").to(options.getOutputFile()).withoutSharding());

    p.run();
```

Comment: I checked the function with debug mode and the input is in order

Comment: In your code here, or in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44579354/how-to-order-pcollectionkvstring-long-in-google-dataflow I don't see where you applied the `Top` transform. Can you show where you're applying it?